# How to achieve this transformation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` :-

| City | Territory | Region | Area | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicopee | Springfield MA | Northeast | National | 58761 |
| Feeding Hills | Springfield MA | Northeast | National | 65204 |
| Feeding Hills | Springfield MA | Northeast | National | 79862 |
| Feeding Hills | Springfield MA | Northeast | National | 67247 |
| Holyoke | Springfield MA | Northeast | East | 64347 |
| Holyoke | Worcester MA | Northeast | East | 73473 |

Imputing with average value of target at that level using this codeI have this :

```
for col in columns: #columns=['City', 'Territory`,'Region','Area']
    avg_tar= df.groupby(col).agg(**{'avg_tar_by_'+col: ('Target', np.mean)})
    df = df.merge(avg_tar, on=col)
df = df.drop(columns=columns)
df = df.rename(columns={'avg_tar_by_'+col: col for col in columns})
```

| City | Territory | Region | Area | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58761 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 58761 |
| 70771 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 65204 |
| 70771 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 79862 |
| 70771 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 67247 |
| 68910 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 68910 | 64347 |
| 68910 | 73473 | 68149 | 68910 | 73473 |

I have another dataframe `df2` ;I want to map the categories across all columns for `df2` with the mapping values obtained in `df1` :-

| City | Territory | Region | Area | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicopee | Springfield MA | Northeast | National | 58761 |
| Chicopee | Springfield MA | Northeast | East | 65204 |
| Feeding Hills | Springfield MA | Northeast | East | 79862 |
| Feeding Hills | Worcester MA | Northeast | East | 67247 |
| Feeding Hills | Worcester MA | Northeast | East | 64347 |
| Holyoke | Worcester MA | Northeast | East | 73473 |

Expected Output :

| City | Territory | Region | Area | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58761 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 58761 |
| 58761 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 65204 |
| 70771 | 67084.2 | 68149 | 67768.5 | 79862 |
| 70771 | 73473 | 68149 | 68910 | 67247 |
| 70771 | 73473 | 68149 | 68910 | 64347 |
| 68910 | 73473 | 68149 | 68910 | 73473 |

Comment: the input/output is unclear, please provide everything as DataFrame constructors with meaningful names

Comment: could you elaborate what is unclear?

Comment: The second and last tables are identical

Comment: it's unclear what is `df1`, what is `df2`, why you show 4 tables (we would expect 3: 2 inputs, 1 output). Also providing a DataFrame constructor for all would be really helpful to reproduce the issue (it's otherwise a pain to copy/paste all tables)

Comment: `df1` and `df2` are shown because The mapping values obtained for `df1`  is to be used for `df2`.

Comment: As said, I'd like to help but the inputs are unfortunately unclear to me... I'll skip this question unless a clear set of DataFrame constructors are provided

Comment: We can continue on chat I can explain there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to map the mean `Target` values for each group of each column in `df1` to `df2` - which you can achieve by extracting the mean `Target` values into a dictionary -

```py
# Creating the mapping dict
grouping_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if col != 'Target']
g_map = {g: dict(df1.groupby(g)['Target'].agg('mean')) for g in grouping_cols}

# Mapping from the dict
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for g in g_map:
    df3[g] = df2[g].map(g_map[g])
df3['Target'] = df2['Target']
```

**Output (df3)**

```
    City  Territory  Region     Area  Target
0  58761    67084.2   68149  67768.5   58761
1  58761    67084.2   68149  68910.0   65204
2  70771    67084.2   68149  68910.0   79862
3  70771    73473.0   68149  68910.0   67247
4  70771    73473.0   68149  68910.0   64347
5  68910    73473.0   68149  68910.0   73473
```

Comment: I have added the code I used to impute the average , can we derieve the dictionary from there

Comment: Yes. Your code and mine are doing the same thing - `groupby` and `mean`